# Python function local variable scope during exceptions

Tags: python, exception, scope

Background: I'm doing COM programming of National Instruments' TestStand in Python. TestStand complains if objects aren't "released" properly (it pops up an "objects not released properly" debug dialog box). The way to release the TestStand COM objects in Python is to ensure all variables no longer contain the object—e.g. `del()` them, or set them to `None`. Or, as long as the variables are function local variables, the object is released as soon as the variable goes out of scope when the function ends.

Well, I've followed this rule in my program, and my program releases object properly as long as there are no exceptions. But if I get an exception, then I'm getting the "objects not released" message from TestStand. This seems to indicate that function local variables aren't going out of scope normally, when an exception happens.

Here is a simplified code example:

```
class TestObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("Init " + self.name)
    def __del__(self):
        print("Del " + self.name)

def test_func(parameter):
    local_variable = parameter
    try:
        pass
#        raise Exception("Test exception")
    finally:
        pass
#        local_variable = None
#        parameter = None

outer_object = TestObject('outer_object')
try:
    inner_object = TestObject('inner_object')
    try:
        test_func(inner_object)
    finally:
        inner_object = None
finally:
    outer_object = None
```

When this runs as shown, it shows what I expect:

```
Init outer_object
Init inner_object
Del inner_object
Del outer_object
```

But if I uncomment the `raise Exception...` line, instead I get:

```
Init outer_object
Init inner_object
Del outer_object
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Exception: Test exception
Del inner_object
```

The `inner_object` is deleted late due to the exception.

If I uncomment the lines that set both `parameter` and `local_variable` to `None`, then I get what I expect:

```
Init outer_object
Init inner_object
Del inner_object
Del outer_object
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Exception: Test exception
```

So when exceptions happen in Python, what exactly happens to function local variables? Are they being saved somewhere so they don't go out of scope as normal? What is "the right way" to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception-handling is probably creating reference loops by keeping references to frames. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=frame#the-interpreter-stack) put it:

> **Note** Keeping references to frame
>   objects, as found in the first element
>   of the frame records these functions
>   return *[[NB: "these functions" here refers to
>   some in module `inspect`, but the rest of the
>   paragraph applies more widely!]]*, can cause your program to
>   create reference cycles. Once a
>   reference cycle has been created, the
>   lifespan of all objects which can be
>   accessed from the objects which form
>   the cycle can become much longer even
>   if Python’s optional cycle detector is
>   enabled. If such cycles must be
>   created, it is important to ensure
>   they are explicitly broken to avoid
>   the delayed destruction of objects and
>   increased memory consumption which
>   occurs. Though the cycle detector will
>   catch these, destruction of the frames
>   (and local variables) can be made
>   deterministic by removing the cycle in
>   a `finally` clause. This is also
>   important if the cycle detector was
>   disabled when Python was compiled or
>   using `gc.disable()`. For example:

```
def handle_stackframe_without_leak():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        # do something with the frame
    finally:
        del frame
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure I understand "Your exception-handling is probably creating reference loops by keeping references to frames." So I've added a code example. I'd be interested to know what you think of it.

Comment: @Craig, no reference loops, but still longer-lived references than you might like, because all the frames in the stack (and therefore their references to objects) must survive as long as the exception is being dealt with (when you set to None all those references, then objects can get removed even though the frames still survive).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14719709/60075), it is possible to [inspect local variables on the frame in an exception traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) via `tb_frame.f_locals`. So it does look as though the objects are kept "alive" for the duration of the exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

A function's scope is for the entire function. Handle this in `finally`.